# What does the subscript after euclidean distance notation mean?

Tags: notation, least-squares

Math noob quesetion: What does the "2" subscript mean in the picture below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$||w||_k=(\sum_{i=1}^{p} w_i^k)^\frac{1}{k}$, so noted above second norm is just standard norm in Euclidean space.